# Does the Glossy BSDF include Fresnel and geometrical attenuation factors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

The analytical Torrance-Sparrow BRDF model incorporates a Fresnel reflectance factor and a geometrical attenuation factor.

Does anybody know if these effects are also considered by the Glossy BSDF material in the Cycles render engine?

Comment: Visually, I don't think it incorporates fresnel. But I can't find anything to back up my claim right now.